# Demora en devolverme los datos a mi select con Ajax - jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tengo un pequeño problema a la hora de implementar el botón editar me trae todos los datos de una manera rápida en mis inpust, pero mi `select` se demora.

```
obtener_unidad_registro();// Son las funciones donde lleno mi combo
obtener_categoria_registro();// Son las funciones donde lleno mi combo
```

Este es mi **Jquery** con mi **Ajax**:

```
function  modificar_producto(codigo) {

    bordes_limpias();
    obtener_unidad_registro();
    obtener_categoria_registro();

    $.ajax({
        url: baseurl + 'Producto/obtener_producto',
        type: "POST",
        data: {codigo: codigo},
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (data)
        {
            $('#codigo_producto').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#nombre_producto').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#codigo_producto').val(data[0]['codigo_producto']);
            $('#nombre_producto').val(data[0]['nombre']);
            $('#precio_entrada').val(data[0]['precio_entrada']);
            $('#precio_salida').val(data[0]['precio_salida']);
            $('#stock_actual').val(data[0]['stock_actual']);
            $('#stock_minimo').val(data[0]['stock_minimo']);
            $("#modal_form_producto").unbind();
            $('#modal_form_producto').modal('show')
            var unidad = data[0]['unidad'];
            var categoria = data[0]['categoria'];
            $("#cb_categoria option[value='" + categoria + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');
            $("#cb_unidad option[value='" + unidad + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');
            $('#boton_multiuso').attr("onclick", 'actualizar_producto(' + codigo + ')');
            $('#msg_cabecera').html("EDITAR PRODUCTO #" + codigo);
        }
    });
}
```

**LAS FUNCIONES DE LOS COMBOS**

```
function obtener_unidad_registro() {
    $.ajax({
        url: baseurl + 'Producto/obtener_unidad',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (data)
        {
            $('#cb_unidad').empty();
            $('#cb_unidad').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#cb_unidad').append(data);
        }
    });
}

function obtener_categoria_registro() {
    $.ajax({
        url: baseurl + 'Producto/obtener_categoria',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (data)
        {
            $('#cb_categoria').empty();
            $('#cb_categoria').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#cb_categoria').append(data);
        }
    });
}
```

**CONTROLADOR**

```
public function obtener_unidad() {
        $niveles = $this->producto->obtener_unidad();
        $resp = '<option name="" value="">--SELECCIONE UNIDAD--</option>';
        foreach ($niveles as $row) {
            $resp .= '<option name="' . $row ['id_unidad'] . '"  value="' . $row ['nombre'] . '">' . $row ['nombre'] . '</option>';
        }
        echo json_encode($resp);
    }

    public function obtener_categoria() {
        $niveles = $this->producto->obtener_categoria();
        $resp = '<option name="" value="">--SELECCIONE CATEGORIA--</option>';
        foreach ($niveles as $row) {
            $resp .= '<option name="' . $row ['id_categoria'] . '" value="' . $row ['nombre'] . '">' . $row ['nombre'] . '</option>';
        }
        echo json_encode($resp);
    }
```

**MODELO**

```
public function obtener_unidad() {
        $query = $this->db_venta->query("SELECT * FROM unidad");
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    public function obtener_categoria() {
        $query = $this->db_venta->query("SELECT * FROM categoria");
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

**Entro a la vista y voy a editar un producto 'X'**
y me sale esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Después de varios intentos recién me sale esto**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no tendriamos que ver si hay algun problema con los querys que llenan esos combos?? no se si tenga que ver.. pero seria interesante...

Answer (score 0):

Lo que usted hace en el modelo yo lo hago en el controlador ejemplo y agrego los datos dinamicamente pero en el js.

CONTROLADOR

```
    public function obtener_unidad() {
                $resp = $this->db_venta->query("SELECT * FROM categoria");
    //si tiene creado el modelo de categoria es mucho mas facil
   // $resp =Categoria::all();
                 echo json_encode($resp);
                }
```

ahora en el java script  de respuesta

```
function obtener_categoria_registro() {
    $.ajax({
        url: baseurl + 'Producto/obtener_categoria',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (data)
        {
              var m=data.length;
           for(var t=0; t<m; t=t+1) {
                            var datos = data[t];

$('#cb_categoria').append('<option name="' + data['id_categoria'] + '" value="' + data['nombre'] + '">' +data['nombre'] + '</option>');

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Uso CI como Framework es por eso que tengo que utilizar MVC